# Why do I never see the prototype property in JavaScript code I edit?

Tags: javascript

Why do I never see [the prototype property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_prototype_array.asp) in JavaScript code I edit, from books and documentation I've read, it seems to be a cornerstone of the language.

Comment: Where are you **expecting** to see it?  What code are you editing?

Comment: I am expecting to see people assigning new methods to classes as in the case of the w3c example.

Comment: Wow, I think that's the worst thing I've seen from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_prototype_array.asp).... the example doesn't really shows the real purpose of making an inherited property, and the description is just wrong and it only creates confusion: `Prototype is a global property which is available with almost all JavaScript objects.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the work i've done, `prototype` usually gets abandoned in favor of closure methods defined within the constructor so I can have private members in my javascript class. i'm aware that `prototype` may serve a purpose when setting up inherited classes but i've never needed to approach that level of complexity.

Comment: For which the price you pay is greater memory use and slower constructors.

Comment: This sounds like the most likely answer to me. (difficult to choose a winner for this question) cheers

Comment: Possibly it was difficult to choose a winner because the question was rather vague and therefore difficult to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because the majority of all javascript coders never cared to learn the basics of the language, and because loose approach allows for a lot of different ways of solving things.

Comment: this is what I am suspicious of

Answer (score 0):

The `prototype` property only exists on `Function` objects. Other objects do not have a `prototype` property. It refers to the object that is used as the prototype for any object created by that function when used as a constructor.

```
function Thing() {
}

Thing.prototype = {
    foo: "bar"
};

var t = new Thing();
window.alert(t.foo);
```

Comment: That's not really correct; all objects have a prototype that's *determined* by their constructor function. True, it's not available via an attribute called "prototype", but it's there. And of course any object *can* have an attribute called "prototype."

Comment: That's why I was careful to refer to it as a "`prototype` property". I'm well aware that an object has a prototype that is determined by its constructor, and I mentioned it in my answer. It's a fair point that one could assign and use a `prototype` property on non-Function objects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if an example is a solution, but this is an example of using a prototype.

Group.prototype['somethin'] must be defined, but Group.prototype exists when you create a new Group.

```
function Group(ob){
    if(!ob || typeof ob!= 'object') ob= {};
    for(var p in ob){
        if(ob.hasOwnProperty(p)) this[p]= ob[p];
    }
}
Group.prototype.merge= function(ob, force){
    var tem, p, force= force!== false;
    if(ob && ob.hasOwnProperty){
        for(p in ob){
            if(ob.hasOwnProperty(p)){
                tem= this[p];
                if(tem=== undefined || force) this[p]= ob[p];
            }
        }
    }
    return this;
}
Group.prototype.assignTo= function(ob, ob2, force){
    return this.merge.call(ob, ob2, force);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

What IDE are you using? Try [visual web developer express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/web/)